# How to get a slice of a list sorted by similarity?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am new to SQLalchemy. And in the documentation, I didn't find what I needed.

The task is to get the first N-th values from the database, sorted by the similarity of some field with some string.

Please tell me how to do this.

**P.S.**

My model:

```
class Place(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'places'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)

    name = Column(String)
    country = Column(String)
```

For example, the database contains such lines:

```
abrzefg, country5
nupvrzz, country8
ekbianq, country2
abrdefg, country3
sezovcl, country1
abcdefg, country7
wznkpdg, country6
nwphtbj, country4
```

I would like to use something like this

```
pattern = 'abcde'
slice = db.query(models.Place).filter(similarity(
    models.Place.name, pattern
)).top(3)
```

And get this:

```
abcdefg, country7
abrdefg, country3
abrzefg, country5
```

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Comment: added clarification

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution

```
from sqlalchemy import desc, func


places = db.query(models.Place).order_by(desc(func.similarity(
    models.Place.name, pattern
))).limit(3).all()
```